# Ava testing is not working with vue single file components

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ava

Issue is the following.

I try to setup "ava" testing for vuejs.
I can't test directly, cause it is impossible to test single file components.
Have found the following instruction:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-node

Created helper (setup.js):

```
const browserEnv = require('browser-env');
const hook = require('vue-node');
const { join } = require('path');

browserEnv();

hook(join(__dirname, 'webpack.config.test.js'));
```

And put it to the root folder.

Than in the package.json have put the following:

```
"ava": {
    "require": [
      "setup.js",
    ]
  }
```

But then I catch error:

> Could not resolve required module 'setup.js'

I use laravel + vue.
vue-node and browser-env have been also installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the path:
"./resources/assets/js/test/helpers/setup.js"